# SlimDX RawInput with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, slimdx, raw-input

I'm trying to set up keyboard and mouse controls for a space game using SlimDX and RawInput. My current code is as follows:

```
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.Keyboard, DeviceFlags.None);
Device.KeyboardInput += new EventHandler<KeyboardInputEventArgs>(keyboardInput);
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.Mouse, DeviceFlags.None);
Device.MouseInput += new EventHandler<MouseInputEventArgs>(mouseInput);
```

However I read here: http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/detail?id=785 that for WPF I need to use a different overload for `Device.RegisterDevice()`, as well as assigning a HandleMessage using `Device.HandleMessage(IntPtr message)`

I've found the correct overload for RegisterDevice() which is:

```
RegisterDevice(UsagePage usagePage, UsageId usageId, DeviceFlags flags, IntPtr target, bool addThreadFilter)
```

What I can't work out, though, is:

1) Now that I have to use a target, what am I meant to set as a target?

2) Where do I get this IntPtr message from?

Comment: Isn't it asking for your window handle?

Comment: For the target? I thought it might be, but I've been unable to test it properly without solving part 2.

Comment: You can get the handle of a WPF window using the System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper class, just create a new instance passing the window reference as a constructor parameter and it's Handle property is the IntPtr

Comment: Oh, I see. So if that's the handle, what gets passed in as the target? Or should I just be setting that to null. Sadly the SlimDX docs don't actually mention what it relates to, and this is one of the cases where it diverges from the C++ DirectX SDK

Answer (score 2):

This might help, I made this for a game of pong. Hope it helps

```
            private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            spaceKeyDown = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            spaceKeyUp = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            spaceKeyW = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            spaceKeyS = true;
        }
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                direction = rand.Next(1, 5);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            spaceKeyDown = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            spaceKeyUp = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            spaceKeyW = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            spaceKeyS = false;
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (spaceKeyDown == true)
        {
            if (p2y < picPicture.Height - Paddle2.Height)
                p2y += 15;
        }
        if (spaceKeyUp == true)
        {
            if (p2y > 0)
                p2y -= 15;
        }
        if (spaceKeyS == true)
        {
            if (p1y < picPicture.Height - Paddle1.Height)
                p1y += 15;
        }
        if (spaceKeyW == true)
        {
            if (p1y > 0)
                p1y -= 15;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Dylan - that's actually the system I have working right now. I was hoping, however to get something that used RawInput to parse controls as I've heard it can be more responsive (and I'm doing a space shooter - so controller lag could be disastrous in a big fight).